# Javascript is losing a backtrace in the catch block

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, stack-trace

The following code sample:

```js
async function expectResolutionErrorCode(object) {
  try {
    await Promise.resolve(1);
    object.f1() // caught error
  } catch (error) {
    object.f2() // uncaught error
  }
}

expectResolutionErrorCode(undefined).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Produces the following backtrace when run using node v14:

```
$ node  test.ts
TypeError: Cannot read property 'f2' of undefined
    at expectResolutionErrorCode (/Users/bogdan/makabu/unstoppable/resolution/test.ts:6:12)
```

If I comment out the `await` statement at line 3 from the sample, the backtrace is complete:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'f2' of undefined
    at expectResolutionErrorCode (/Users/bogdan/makabu/unstoppable/resolution/test.ts:6:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bogdan/makabu/unstoppable/resolution/test.ts:10:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

So the `await` statement clearly causes node to lose some part of the backtrace.
Why does it behave like that?
Is there any workaround to maintain the backtrace while still using `await` statements inside `try` `catch`?

I tested this behavior in Chrome and Safari and the stacktrace is lost in almost the same way: https://jsfiddle.net/61kdv8fx/

Comment: Are you transpiling your code? For me, Node v14 shows async call traces just fine.

Comment: Side note: You don't need the `Promise.resolve` in your `await Promise.resolve(1);` (though of course it may be useful for emphasis), `await 1;` behaves the exact same way (per specification). `await` effectively calls `Promise.resolve` on its operand, and if you give `Promise.resolve` a promise whose constructor is `Promise`, it returns that same promise; it only wraps non-promise values (including thenables from 3rd party libs) and promises created by a different constructor (such as a subclass).

Answer (score 4):

It's because the stack has unwound. Remember that `await` is syntactic sugar for hooking the settlement of a promise. So when you reach the `await` in your code, the function returns. **Later**, when the code continues because the promise was settled, the stack is shallow because promise reactions are called directly.

JavaScript tool makers are **very** aware of this and working on async call stacks to address it.

**However**, I should note that when I try to replicate what you're seeing on Node v14, I don't see it, because V8 already has async call stacks. Example:

```
async function example() {
    try {
        await Promise.resolve(1); // Could just be `await 1;`, but I wanted to match the question
        throw new Error("boom1");
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error("boom2");
    }
}

async function a() {
    await b();
}

async function b() {
    await c()
}

async function c() {
    await example();
}

a();
```

When I run it:

```
$ node example.js 
(node:5342) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: boom2
    at example (/path/to/example.js:6:15)
    at async c (/path/to/example.js:19:5)
    at async b (/path/to/example.js:15:5)
    at async a (/path/to/example.js:11:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:5342) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5342) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I get the same sort of output on modern versions of Chrome and other browsers using a recent V8. But Firefox v78 still loses the context; I'm sure the SpiderMonkey team are working on it.